# Calculating large numbers in C++ without external libraries

Tags: c++, numbers

I need to write a program that will perform operations on float numbers higher than 10^100.
I can't use any arbitrary precision mathematics libraries that are not included in GCC package by default.
I have NO idea how how to go about it.
Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: "Float numbers"? IEEE 754 double takes values up to 10^308, so you don't need arbitrary precision math for this.

Comment: @ybungalobill The C spec implies `DBL_MAX` must be at least `1E+37`, but that is unfortunately less than 10^100.  Same for `LDBL_MAX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class that can store larger numbers. 12345678 equals to 1234 * 10e4 + 5678.

Comment: Storing large numbers is never a problem, the math on it yet...

Answer (score 0):

For large numbers I use string buffers and do manual computation on it. It is much overhead and slow but you get infinite precision.